# How to loop this object with jQuery/javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, loops

I am looking for a way to pass values to a couple of elements, in this case every list item(li) should have a classname(or id) and a font color. The values are stored in a object(the example below is called JSON data right?).

So how can i use loop all elements in order to get the right values?

Object

```
var list = {'red-class':'red', 'black-class':'black', 'green-class':'green'};
```

An idea how i want to loop it(this is not working ofcourse)

```
$('li').each(function(key, value){

   $(this).addClass(key).css({color: value})
});
```

Comment: it's not clear exactly what you want the output to be. Could you provide the final state of the `<li>` elements after this whole thing is applied, you can edit your question and add them at the end.

Comment: Object properties are not ordered. How do you figure out which class, color belongs to which list elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var styles = [];
for (var key in list) {
  styles.push({className:key, color: list[key]};
}

$('li').each(function(index, element){
   $(element).addClass(styles[index].className).css({color: styles[index].color})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in list) {
  var value = list[key];
  elem.classList.add(key);
  elem.style.color = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as if you should do this with css:

```
li.red {
    color: red;
}
```

And so on. If that doesn't work (for whatever reason?!), and assuming that you mean that each `li` already has a class `[red|black|green]`, you would:

```
$('li').each(function(item) {
    $(this).css("color", list[this.className + "-class"]);
}
```

But this is only if you *only* have the color as class, i.e. not "fooItem red", that won't work. Again, why not use css?

***UPDATE:*** Ok, so you want to loop over your object `list`, getting each key and value. How will you select which element to apply each rule to?

```
for(var key in list) {
    $("some selector).addClass(key).css("color", list[key]);
}
```

Again, I'm sure you don't want to apply each rule to the same element, so you need to tell us what you want to accomplish.

Comment: CSS is not an option, as this example above is not what i am looking for, i just made it very simple so that everybody understands what i mean(i hope).

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a javascript object (not to be confused with JSON).

```
var counter = 0;
$.each(list, function (key, value) {
    $('li')[counter].addClass(key).css('color', value);
    counter++;
});
```

Edit: added counter

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not "JSON data." Your `list` variable is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals). To loop over the keys of an object you would use the `for..in` construct:

```
var list = {'red-class':'red', 'black-class':'black', 'green-class':'green'},
    key, value;

for (key in list) {
  if (!list.hasOwnproperty(key)) {
    continue;
  }
  console.log("list[" + key + "] = " + list[key]);
}
```

JSON is a notation that uses the JavaScript object literal, or array literal, syntax to represent arbitrary data. See [json.org](http://json.org/) or the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) for more information.

Also, if you want to write your `list` object as JSON, it would be:

```
{"red-class":"red", "black-class":"black","green-class":"green"}
```

Not the use of double quotes instead of single quotes. Single quotes are invalid JSON according to [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info, i know some thing but not how they are named(makes it always hard to ask). Okoay so it needs double quotes to be JSON. Thanks for the information!!!

Comment: That's not what I was saying. In your JavaScript, the declaration is a JavaScript object literal not JSON. If you want to write your JavaScript object literal as JSON, _outside_ of your JavaScript, then you would need to use double quotes. For example, if you stored your data at http://example.com/list.json then you would be writing JSON instead of JavaScript.